# Why is a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError raised when I run my JAR with Apache Storm ? (org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig)

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I started last week a formation in Kafka and Storm at OpenClassRooms. During practical work, I encounter an error when I try to execute a JAR containing my java code for Storm.

No problem when compiling the project in Java, no problem when packaging with maven, the problem only occurs when running the JAR

```
theirman@vm-debian:/data/eclipse-workspace/velos$ storm jar target/velos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar velos.App remote
Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/apps/storm -Dstorm.log.dir=/apps/storm/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64 -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /apps/storm/*:/apps/storm/lib/*:/apps/storm/extlib/*:target/velos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/apps/storm/conf:/apps/storm/bin: -Dstorm.jar=target/velos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dstorm.dependency.jars= -Dstorm.dependency.artifacts={} velos.App remote
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig
    at velos.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

**App.java**

```
package velos;

import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AuthorizationException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseWindowedBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException 
    {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder<String, String> spoutConfigBuilder = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("localhost:9092", "velib-stations");
        spoutConfigBuilder.setGroupId("city-stats");
        KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> spoutConfig = spoutConfigBuilder.build();

        builder.setSpout("stations", new KafkaSpout<String, String>(spoutConfig));

        builder.setBolt("station-parsing", new StationParsingBolt()).shuffleGrouping("stations");
        builder.setBolt("city-stats", new CityStatsBolt().withTumblingWindow(BaseWindowedBolt.Duration.of(1000*60*5))).fieldsGrouping("station-parsing", new Fields("city"));
        builder.setBolt("save-results",  new SaveResultsBolt()).fieldsGrouping("city-stats", new Fields("city"));

        StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(60*30);
        String topologyName = "velos";
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("remote")) {
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
        else 
        {
            LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
            cluster.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>velos</groupId>
  <artifactId>velos</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>velos</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
          <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from your pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storm-kafka or storm-kafka-client likely are not provided on the storm classpath, so you would need to remove the scope from those

Then you will also want to try shading your JAR so that all dependencies are available at runtime