# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am currently learning how to use apache storm and apache kafka by following courses provided by OpenClassRoom and my question is very similar to the ones we can find
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322807/why-is-a-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-raised-when-i-run-my-jar-with-apache-sto) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383547/why-is-a-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-raised-org-apache-storm-kafka-spout-kaf).I have tried to solve my problem with the information provided on these posts but nothing changes, I still have the same error.

I can compile the code on `eclipse` and can use the command `mvn package` without any issue. I put everything I've found that reffered to `kafka` and `storm` in the `pom.xml`.
Any advice would help me a lot.
You can find bellow the `pom` and the code.

The `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>velib</groupId>
  <artifactId>velib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>velib</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <scope>provied</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
          <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>org.apache.storm:storm-core</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.slf4j</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

and the code :

```java
 package velib;


import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AuthorizationException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseWindowedBolt;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )throws Exception, AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException
    {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder<String, String> spoutConfigBuilder = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("localhost:9092", "velib-stations");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "city-stats");
        spoutConfigBuilder.setProp(prop);
        KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> spoutConfig = spoutConfigBuilder.build();
        builder.setSpout("stations", new KafkaSpout<String, String>(spoutConfig));

        builder.setBolt("station-parsing", new StationParsingBolt())
            .shuffleGrouping("stations");

        builder.setBolt("city-stats", new CityStatsBolt().withTumblingWindow(BaseWindowedBolt.Duration.of(1000*60*5)))
            .fieldsGrouping("station-parsing", new Fields("city"));

        builder.setBolt("save-results",  new SaveResultsBolt())
            .fieldsGrouping("city-stats", new Fields("city"));

        StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(60*30);
        String topologyName = "velib";
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("remote")) {
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
        else {
            LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
            cluster.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove old version of `storm-kafka`, and Kafka server dependency `kafka_2.13` since you only need `storm-kafka-client`

Working Maven packaging only means your code compiled. You need to use [assembly plugin (preferred)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729054/2308683) or shade plugins (as answered in linked question) to *include Storm Kafka client libraries as part of your JAR*. You might also want to put `<scope>provided</scope>` on the storm-core dependency.

**edit**

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <storm.version>2.4.0</storm.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${storm.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```bash
$ jar tf target/untitled-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep KafkaSpoutConfig
org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutConfig.class
```